# Two implementations of creating adjacency lists from graph

Tags: c

For the  following declaration of graph (which I cannot change - assignment; also macros are there because I'm not allowed to use '.' and '->' operators for graph)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAG(vp)   ((vp)->tag)
#define LABEL(vp) ((vp)->label)  
#define EDGE(vp)  ((vp)->edge)

typedef struct vertex 
{
    char tag;
    char *label;
    struct vertex *edge[1];
}
vertex, *vp;
```

and this declaration of adjacency list (for this one and all the next code I can do whatever I want)

```
typedef struct adjList
{
    vp node;
    struct adjList *next;
}
adjList;
```

I wrote two versions of a function that must create adjacency list representation from graph. Both of them use this function to create one list.

```
adjList *createList (vp graph)
{
    int i;
    adjList *result, *ptr, *ptr2;
    if (graph)
    {
        result = malloc (sizeof (adjList));
        result->node = graph;
        ptr2 = result;
        for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
        {
            ptr = malloc (sizeof (adjList));
            ptr->node = EDGE (graph)[i];
            ptr2->next = ptr;
            ptr2 = ptr;
        }
        ptr2->next = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The first one returns an array of adjacency lists (as a double pointer) but does this only for one node and its children (I haven't figured out how to return the full representation with this working function)

```
adjList **createLists (vp graph)
{
    int i;
    adjList **result;
    result = malloc (sizeof (adjList *));
    result[0] = createList (graph);
    for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
    {
        result = realloc (result, sizeof (adjList *) * (i + 2));
        result[i + 1] = createList (EDGE (graph)[i]);
    }
    result = realloc (result, sizeof (adjList *) * (i + 2));
    result[i + 1] = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

The second one yields segmentation fault. Basically, it creates an array of empty lists, but using this logic I would create full representation.

```
void createListsHelper (adjList **result, vp graph, int *index) /* index stores an index in an array to create there next list */
{
    int i;
    if (graph)
    {
        result = realloc (result, sizeof (adjList *) * (*index + 2));
        result[*index] = createList (graph);
        for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
        {
            ++(*index);
            createListsHelper (result, EDGE (graph)[i], index);
        }
    }
}

adjList **createLists (vp graph)
{
    adjList **result = malloc (sizeof (adjList *));
    int *index = malloc (sizeof (int));
    *index = 0;
    createListsHelper (result, graph, index);
    result[*index + 1] = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

How can I change one of them so that they would work as they should.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I used the following "main" to test them.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    adjList **list, *ptr;
    vp test;
    test = malloc (sizeof (vertex) + 4 * sizeof (vp));
    LABEL (test) = malloc (sizeof (char) * 2);
    LABEL (test)[0] = 'a';
    LABEL (test)[1] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        EDGE (test)[i] = malloc (sizeof (vertex));
    }
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[0]) = malloc (sizeof (char) * 2);
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[0])[0] = 'b';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[0])[1] = '\0';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[1]) = malloc (sizeof (char) * 2);
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[1])[0] = 'c';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[1])[1] = '\0';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[2]) = malloc (sizeof (char) * 2);
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[2])[0] = 'd';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[2])[1] = '\0';
    EDGE (test)[3] = NULL;
    EDGE (EDGE (test)[0])[0] = NULL;
    EDGE (EDGE (test)[1])[0] = NULL;
    EDGE (EDGE (test)[2])[0] = NULL;
    list = createLists2 (test);
    for (i = 0; list[i]; ++i)
    {
        for (ptr = list[i]; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
        {
            printf ("%c ", LABEL (ptr->node)[0]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do some debugging first, and then reduce all of this code to a simple test case.

Comment: i cannot reduce from this state, have asked this question so many times, simplified as best as i could, tried to debug, wrote my observations, what do you want? if i could do it, i would

Comment: If you're trying to fix a seg-fault, you should run your code in a debugger to discover which line causes the problem, then work backwards by inspecting values of variables, etc., and comparing them to what you expect to occur.  But you can't just paste all your code on SO and hope that someone will fix it for you...

Comment: i wrote that it creates empty lists, so it is OBVIOUS that it would give segfault on print line

Comment: and don't ask me to write some print lines inside my functions - that didn't work either, everything was printed perfectly when i've inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void createListsHelper (adjList **result, vp graph, int *index) /* index stores an index in an array to create there next list */
{
    int i;
    if (graph)
    {
        result = realloc (result, sizeof (adjList *) * (*index + 2));
```

Since `result` is passed by value (*every* parameter is passed by value in C), this modification will not affect `result` in the calling function. This line

```
createListsHelper (result, graph, index);
result[*index + 1] = NULL; /* <<< */
```

invokes UB (because `result` is still pointing to an array of 1 `int`, and you are accessing the second element).